# MongoDb + C# - get functions of the database

Tags: c#, mongodb

Good day all,

The questions is: How could I access **functions' definitions** from the MongoDb database object?

```
        const string connectionString = "mongodb://localhost";

        // Create a MongoClient object by using the connection string
        var client = new MongoClient(connectionString);

        //Use the MongoClient to access the server
        MongoServer server = client.GetServer();

        // Use the server to access the 'local' database
        var database = server.GetDatabase("local");

        //What next?
        //.................................................
```

Comment: What do you mean by function's definitions? As in functions you have in MongoDb? Or like the help log from the console?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I mean custom user-defined functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean get them as in get the value of the function code itself, they are stored in the `system.js` collection for a database. Get them all as with any other collection:

```
db.system.js.find({});
```

In C#:

```
var database = server.GetDatabase("databaseName");

var collection = database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("system.js");
var filter = new BsonDocument();
var count = 0;
using (var cursor = await collection.FindAsync(filter))
{
    while (await cursor.MoveNextAsync())
    {
        var batch = cursor.Current;
        foreach (var document in batch)
        {
            // process document
            count++;
        }
    }
}
```

If you mean call them within code, if `system.js` contains an object `{ _id: "two", value: "function(x, y) { return x + y; }" }`, you can call the function by doing as follows in the loop:

```
database.Eval(document.getValue("value")).ToString();
```